# Nvidia mx130 cannot be installed in HP Pavilion,also want to know about hdmi and usb c. (it uses nvidia optimus technology)

Tags: linux, multi-monitor, hdmi, optimus

I tried almost every process but nvidia mx130 din not load to karnel. I used ubuntu, pop os and fedora. Actually I need a second monitor, it has 1 HDMI, 1 usb c and 2 usb A ports. how to know which ports are connected to my iGPU?(as nvidia is not working)
mx130 is not a VGA adapter; it only does 3D.

lspci | grep VGA 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]

lspci -nn | grep '[03' 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] [8086:3ea0] 02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] [10de:174d] (rev a2)

I have no knowledge about hardware, please help me, I need a second monitor whether nvidia can be used or not, with iGPU how can be done this?

neofetch result added.

[image: neofetch]

Comment: 1. Typically, in hybrid graphics, the external video outputs are only connected to the dGPU (Nvidia). 2. Nvidia almost always requires proprietary drivers to enable those video outputs. 3. Nvidia drivers are unsigned therefore they don't work with Secure Boot unless manually signed (unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 you can disable Secure Booit).